# Getting SQL error of claimsStatus-InlineParameterMap. on deploying the war file

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, sybase, ibatis

Getting the following error on starting a server to create a war.deploy file
Using Jboss EAP-7

No problem with the SQL query as it is working perfectly fine in the database

The error occurred in com/urn/roadrunner/claim/dao/ClaimsLookupDao.xml.
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the claimsStatus-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: fakqyppr0..CMC_MCTR_CD_TRANS not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).

```
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hello`, so

```
java.sql.SQLException: fakqyppr0..CMC_MCTR_CD_TRANS not found.
```

It is actually an issue with the DB, where the table `CMC_MCTR_CD_TRANS` is not being found. The snippet of exception you posted has no issues.